# How do I correct this z-index and button pics?

Tags: html, css, background

So I'm new to coding and Iv been playing around over the past 2 days and so far I have this setup...

---

### This is a re-edit of my origional post.

notes:

The i (br) makes the body scroll for now.

Otherwise the code is exactly how I want it.

I'v read up a bit and found parent relations dont work out so well with z-indexes so from what I gathered I think the divs are all siblings.

So far my z-index is a 2 layer set-up, 100's being the first layer, 10's being the second inside that first.

My tab selectors wont show up which I eventually will code with css3 transformations as a continuous slide over the tabBar classes, but for now I need to know how to get them to appear.

---

```
<head style="margin:0;">

  <style>

    .tabBarbackground {
                       background-color:rgb(56, 56, 56);
                       width:1440px;
                       height:50px;
                       position:fixed;
                       left:0px;
                       top:0px;
                       z-index:110;
                      }

    .tabBargradiant {
                     background:linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(34,34,34,1),rgba(34,34,34,0),rgba(34,34,34,1));
                     width:1440px;
                     height:50px;
                     position:fixed;
                     left:0px;
                     top:0px;
                     z-index:120;
                    }

    .tabSelector {
                  opacity:0.2;
                  background:linear-gradiant(0deg,rgba(204,147,90,1),rgba(204,147,90,.5),rgba(204,147,90,1));
                  width:480px;
                  height:50px;
                  position:fixed;
                  left:0px;
                  top:0px;
                  z-index:210;
                 }

    .tabSelectordefinition {
                            opacity:0.4;
                            background-color:(rgba(204,147,90,.8));
                            width:480px;
                            height:10px;
                            position:fixed;
                            left:0px;
                            top:50px;
                            z-index:220;
                           }

    .buttonFrame1 {
                   width:480px;
                   height:50px;
                   background-image:url("http://i1383.photobucket.com/albums/ah281/ScrapBookSearch/YellowTvGuide_zpsvtnwvwui.png");
                   background-color:transparent;
                   background-repeat:no-repeat;
                   background-size:contain;
                   background-position:center;
                   border:none;
                   position:fixed;
                   left:0px;
                   top:0px;
                   z-index:410;
                  }

    .buttonFrame2 {
                   width:480px;
                   height:50px;
                   background-image:url("http://i1383.photobucket.com/albums/ah281/ScrapBookSearch/WatchSeries_zpsgppfggg9.png");
                   background-color:transparent;
                   background-repeat:no-repeat;
                   background-size:contain;
                   background-position:center;
                   border:none;
                   position:fixed;
                   left:480px;
                   top:0px;
                   z-index:420;
                  }

    .buttonFrame3 {
                   width:480px;
                   height:50px;
                   background-image:url("http://i1383.photobucket.com/albums/ah281/ScrapBookSearch/ZmovieFakeReel_zpssqqo7bty.png");
                   background-color:transparent;
                   background-repeat:no-repeat;
                   background-size:contain;
                   background-position:center;
                   border:none;
                   position:fixed;
                   left:960px;
                   top:0px;
                   z-index:430;
                  }

  </style>

</head>

<body style="margin:0;">

  <div class="tabBarbackground">

  </div>

  <div class="tabBargradiant">

  </div>

  <div class="tabSelector">

  </div>

  <div class="tabSelectordefinition">

  </div>

  <button class="buttonFrame1">

  </button>

  <button class="buttonFrame2">

  </button>

  <button class="buttonFrame3">

  </button>

  <p> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br> i <br>


</body>
```

---

Anyone who can shed some light on this error please let me know?

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Its a basic fixed topmenu with css3 transitions which arent in place yet. Ill plug links in later when i get my web host.

Comment: Yes, and you've hidden your buttons by setting their opacity to 0.. why?

Comment: So I can see the gradiant. The tab selector will highlight and transition with color maby. I dont have a perfect plan yet, just poking around and need some help. The buttons will just be a setup for a function using node.js and all I need is a click spot.

Comment: I just got what ilia ment by why opacity. It hid the entire button which was an over site on my part. I still dont know how to make the tab selector pieces show though. Ill re-edit my post as soon as I put this new setup together.

Comment: You can change the opacity of the button's background with rgba. That way the buttons will be visible but transparent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description is not entirely clear, however I think you may be going about this the wrong way. For something like this, I tend to rely more on the position rules alone, using position:relative and position:absolute to lay elements on top of each other. I only resort to z-index if for some reason position adjustments are not possible or practical. Although you are correct that z-indexing can be problematic, mainly due to cross browser compatibility.

But in this case, your problem seems to be a simple misspelling of the word gradient:

Misspelled:

```
background:linear-gradiant(0deg,rgba(204,147,90,1),rgba(204,147,90,.5),rgba(204,147,90,1));
```

Correct Spelling:

```
background:linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(204,147,90,1),rgba(204,147,90,.5),rgba(204,147,90,1));
```

But take a look at your code here: [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEgEMe)

I added a plain background color to the .tabSelector class and the background appeared. Not sure if the positioning you have there there is desirable, but based on your code, that is what you got.

Comment: Thank you so much! Its been years since I properly wrote any documents up and general chat in gaming has led to improper use of the english language.

Comment: No problem. Please mark this answer as the correct response since this resolved the issue. Thank you for sharing.